# How to add upside edged underline in edittext android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to add this type of underline in edittext

[image: example]

xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/InputLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

style

```
<style name="InputLayout" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_draw</item>
</style>
```

but when it got focused it shows it's own underline along with background drawable and and as you can see the drawable i am using is not working good as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create xml file like edit_text_design.xml and save it to your drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- underline color -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#41e3ec" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item
    android:bottom="1.5dp"
    android:left="1.5dp"
    android:right="1.5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="5.0dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Then use it in your xml for EditText like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Name"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

No theam needed..

Output like this
[image]

Comment: it worked but can you tell me how to draw some gap between underline and text same as sample image and how to change it's states like normal and focused because at the current state it carries only one color in every state

Comment: Just add padding like ...  android:padding="5dp"

Comment: I've figured it out by myself Thanks for your support i really appreciate it

Comment: android:padding="5dp" means all side 5dp .... you can specify android:paddingLeft , android:paddingRight, android:paddigTop, android:paddingBottom as you want...

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the background from the EditText inside layout, because it has its own.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to change the state behavior along with Enamul Haque answer

create a drawable and assign it Edittext

Edittext xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/InputLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:background="@drawable/editext_states"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

drawable

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/underline_blue"
    /> <!-- pressed -->
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/underline_red"
    /> <!-- focused -->
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/underline_normal"
    /> <!-- default -->
```

create three drawable and change their color as you like and replace these drawable with that